# Example from pedometer package not working?

Tags: android, flutter, sensors, pedometer

I have installed the blank flutter app with ONLY pedometer package :

```
dependencies:
  pedometer: ^3.0.0
```

And paste [this](https://github.com/cph-cachet/flutter-plugins/blob/master/packages/pedometer/example/lib/main.dart) source, compiled without errors, but in-app :

```
Step Count not available
```

I installed other libraries, they work, what's the point?

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.5, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-RS)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Device data:

```
Samsung Galaxy A10

One UI version
3.1
Android Version
11
Google Play system update
1 April 2021
Krenel version
4.4.17...
```

Chat GPT things:

```
The Flutter pedometer package should be compatible with the Samsung Galaxy A10 running One UI 3.1 and Android 11, 
as well as the Google Play system update from April 2021.
```

Comment: Do you have any error ? If yes, which ones ? Also if you tried that on an emulator, that's completely normal that it doesn't work.

If you tested that on a real device, please include the error you got if you got any.

Answer (score 0):

you should add , permissions to use the package,

For android:

For Android 10 and above add the following permission to the Android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

For ios:

Add the following entries to your Info.plist file in the Runner xcode project:

```
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>This application tracks your steps</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>processing</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, but I forgot, I have put that permission.

Comment: did you enable GPS on your phone,?